# open all website URL within App and external URLs using external browser in WebView?

Tags: android

I have this code, but not because it works, it keeps opening in webview and what I want is that the links do not belong to my website open in your default browser. Any idea? thanks
here is my MainActivity.java

```
package club.moviestreet.www.webviewapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mywebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings= mywebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mywebView.loadUrl("http://moviestreet.club/");
        // Line of Code for opening links in app
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }

    //Code For Back Button
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mywebView.canGoBack())
        {
            mywebView.goBack();
        }

        else
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: implement shouldShowOverloading() callbacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is **[shouldOverrideUrlLoading](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest))** of **WebViewClient**

Give the host application a chance to take over the control when a new url is about to be loaded in the current WebView. If WebViewClient is not provided, by default WebView will ask Activity Manager to choose the proper handler for the url. If WebViewClient is provided, **return true** m**eans the** **host application handles the url**, while **return false means the current WebView handles the url**.

Replace

```
mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

**With this:**

```
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (!url.startsWith("http://moviestreet.club/")) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: i am new to this dont know where to put the new code, plz tell me where i have to put your code

Comment: i did it but now after opening the app no link is opening

Comment: https://gyazo.com/a46a7ce0ceda80aa7b77368de9ea245c                        see there is a line in the code

Comment: import android.content.Intent

Comment: thanks for your help sir its worked now, now i have 1 more thing to add here, the url i need to change when gov ban my domain, then i want when ppl open the app it will update new  url there auto by app update system, for that thing what i have to do?